# How to simplify fractions in my class?

Tags: python

This is my code for class `Fraction`:

```
class Fraction:
    """Class for performing fraction arithmetic.
    Each Fraction has two attributes: a numerator, n and a deconominator, d.
    Both must be integer and the deonominator cannot be zero.
    """
    def __init__(self,n,d):
        """Performs error checking and standardises to ensure denominator is positive"""
        if type(n)!=int or type(d)!=int:
            raise TypeError("n and d must be integers")
        if d==0:
            raise ValueError("d must be positive")
        elif d<0:
            self.n = -n
            self.d = -d
        else:
            self.n = n
            self.d = d

    def __str__(self):
        """Gives string representation of Fraction (so we can use print)"""
        return(str(self.n) + "/" + str(self.d))

    def __add__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the sum of two Fractions"""
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.d + self.d*otherFrac.n
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)

    def __sub__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the difference between two Fractions"""
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.d - self.d*otherFrac.n
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)

    def __mul__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the product of two Fractions"""
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.n
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)

    def __truediv__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the quotient of two Fractions"""
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.d
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.n
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)

    def __eq__(self,otherFrac):
        return(self.n * otherFrac.d) == (self.d * otherFrac.n)
```

To make the class more useful, how can I simplify the fraction?

For example: I want to change 30/15 into 5/3? It looks like:
(30/2)/(18/2) ---> 15/9 -----> (15/3)/(9/3) -----> 5/3

And I not use `import fraction`.

Comment: To simplify fractions you need to use find the [**_greatest common divisor_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of the the fraction's numerator and denominator and then divide both of them by it. This should be repeated until the GCD of the two numbers is 1.

Answer (score 3):

You want to find the *greatest common divisor* of the numerator and the denominator and divide both by that. The [`gcd` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) is in Python's standard library, but you might want to implement it yourself. One famous (and easy to implement) algorithm to find it is called [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

You can implement Euclid's algorithm by subtracting your two numbers to get a third number (the difference), then discarding the biggest number of the three and repeating this subtraction/discard process until one of your numbers is zero.

By the way, 30/15 reduced is 2/1.

To take your example (30/15)

30 - 15 = 15

Now you have 3 numbers (30, 15, 15). Discard the largest and repeat.

15 - 15 = 0

Now you have 3 smaller numbers (15, 15, 0).

15 - 0 = 15

Because that didn't change the set of numbers, you can conclude that 15 is your greatest common divisor. (and if you divide both 30 and 15 by 15, you get 2 and one, which is your reduced fraction's numerator and denominator.

Comment: Yea I knew it. But I want to know how to do it in pythen

Comment: @koko If you understand the algorithm, what's stopping you from translating it into code? You need to specify things like that in your question.

Comment: But how can I do it in code which calculate automatically?

Comment: Google "python gcd function" and you'll find lots of implementations. It's more fun to stare at it for a while and figure it out though :)

Comment: Once you have a gcd function, add a `reduce` method to class that simply replaces `self.n` and `self.d` with `self.n / gcd(self.n, self.d)` and `self.d / gcd(self.n, self.d)` and call that method at the end of  `__init__`, and whatever else changes the numerator or denominator. You shouldn't need it at the end of `__add__` and friends because they already return a new fraction so the `__init__` case will catch them